# SQL Server query creating different return types

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'll go straight with the code, then explain my problem, this way it will be easier. Just to give a heads up, I use entity framework 7 with SQL Server 2014, ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6.

So, I've following classes :

```
public class Base {
    public int BaseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class DerivedOne : Base { 
    public virtual List<OtherDBObject> ListOne { get; set; }  
}
public class DerivedTwo : Base {
    public string SomeContent { get; set; }
}
```

And I created repository that retrievs Base objects from database. Problem is, DerivedOne and DerivedTwo have different members - how can I know which type to return (which members to query further)?

```
public class Repo : IRepo {
    public async Task<Base> GetById(int id) {
        // I though that this method should work something like this (its pseudo code) :
        context.Base.Where(b => b.BaseId == id)
            .switch(obj.type) {
                case DerivedOne : query for OtherDBObjects
                case DerivedTwo : query for string content somewhere else
                ...
            }).First();
    }
}
```

My goal is to have very abstract Base class containing just a few basic fields and derived ones can be completely diffrent.

PS If you have different structure for this task, feel free to post it!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here, but can't you just query for Base objects and then see whether the fetched object is of type DerivedOne or DerivedTwo?

Comment: Well yes, but it would be splitted into two queries to database - one to fetch Base then check it's type and then query derived classes contents. I think it would be better to have one query than two - much less overhead.

Comment: Control flow based on object type checking =  very bad design.

Comment: @E-Bat I know, so that's why I'm asking. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can write good stuff by using generics and extensions methods, something like the following:

```
public static Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync<TEntity>( 
    this DbSet<TEntity> set, int id)  where TEntity : Base
{
    return set.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
DerivedOne entity = await DbContext.DerivedOnes.GetByIdAsync(id);
```

Comment: That's how I would do it if I knew type of entity before querying database. I just want to call api like 'api/lesson/id' and the result would be type with all it's corresponding members. 
My database will be almost always readonly - what do you think about storing static, pre-created content in some key-value (I'm using Azure, so choice would be TableStorage) where key is just id?

Comment: That method does not know what type you are going to query before hand. In your lesson controller/index action is where  you specify the concrete type with the Sample Usage syntax.

Comment: I don't know if I made it clear : I pass only ID to the database, I don't know what type I get until query returns data. Therefore I need to treat it as Base type. In other words : function should only have 'return ..' inside. Something like :
public Base GetById(int id) {
return DbContext.Base.GetById(id);
}
And if data turns out to be of DerivedType, it should include it's members.

Comment: But when you request 'api/lesson/id', don't you know that you want to query a lesson object?

Comment: I know i need to query Lesson but I don't know which derived type I will get, so query doesn't know what foreign data it should retrive additionally. That was my idea - I can easily query lessons by id, not knowing their type. But I see that is bit complicated task, so I think it would be easier to put some constraints on api/queries. And as I said - it will be almost always readonly, so I'll put lessons in table storage with pre-made JSON data.